# How to add API to chat bot or any web sites notification(like twitter)

Tags: azure-language-understanding

i want to create a chat bot using LUIS (ms bot framework) that should have to be integrated with the notification of stock,sports and API like Facebook , twitter notification.
please elaborately explain i am a beginner.

Comment: Can you provide any details about the approach you have tried to solve this problem? I would recommend looking at the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript) on proactive messages and  this Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53424861/microsoft-azure-bot-framework-sdk-4-send-proactive-message-to-specific-users-fr) for help getting started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to go through the Graph Authentication and LUIS samples from the bot builder sample repository on GitHub.
[BotBuilder Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples)